# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, openssl

I'm getting this error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError
SSL_set_tlsext_host_name:

/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'
...
```

Im working on Mac OS X. I already tried reinstalling rvm, openssl (both macports and brew), xcode and different ruby versions and nothing worked.

---

```
/Users/Martin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `block in connect'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
rest-client (1.6.7) lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
oauth (0.4.5) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:164:in `request'
oauth (0.4.5) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:197:in `token_request'
oauth (0.4.5) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:139:in `get_request_token'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/omniauth-af14e6ea9a40/oa-oauth/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:31:in `request_phase'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/omniauth-af14e6ea9a40/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:58:in `request_call'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/omniauth-af14e6ea9a40/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:41:in `call!'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/omniauth-af14e6ea9a40/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/omniauth-af14e6ea9a40/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:44:in `call!'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/omniauth-af14e6ea9a40/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/omniauth-af14e6ea9a40/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:44:in `call!'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/omniauth-af14e6ea9a40/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/omniauth-af14e6ea9a40/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:44:in `call!'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/omniauth-af14e6ea9a40/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30:in `call'
hoptoad_notifier (2.4.11) lib/hoptoad_notifier/rack.rb:27:in `call'
mongoid (2.2.4) lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `block in call'
mongoid (2.2.4) lib/mongoid.rb:130:in `unit_of_work'
mongoid (2.2.4) lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `call'
sass (3.1.10) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
/Users/Martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/client_side_validations-46f8fc087704/lib/client_side_validations/middleware.rb:16:in `call'
warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
```

Comment: What does the rest of the stack trace look like? Have you tried monkey-patching http.rb, adding a breakpoint and using ruby-debug to see what's going on?

Comment: Strange thing is that my friend on different mac doesnt have this issue. I tried reinstalling everything and didnt help

Answer (score 3):

I found the reason of it. I used Mac Postgres installer that modified somehow openssl and gems were build apon it. I removed Postgres install it with brew and all is ok now.